# Broken routes with react app on S3 hosting using s3_website gem

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am using [S3_website](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website) gem to push a react build to my bucket. Everything works great but when I navigate to a custom url and I hit refresh, I get a 404 error because it tries to find this object in the bucket instead of executing the route.

I have the default config in the s3_website yml with no redirect rules.

```
site: dist
index_document: index.html
error_document: error.html
s3_endpoint: us-east-2
cloudfront_wildcard_invalidation: true
```

[image]

What configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your bucket properties under `Error Document` just use the same file as the `Index Document` which should be your `index.html`